# Probability problem about a deck of cards.

Tags: probability

Some cards were thrown away from a standard pack of $52$ cards.  However all four aces were made sure to be kept among the remaining cards.  Four cards were then selected at random from these remaining cards.  If the probability of selecting the four aces is $1/1001$, how many cards were thrown away?

$$\biggl(1-\frac x{48}\biggr). \frac4{52-x} = \frac1{1001} $$

and get $x= 47.95$ which should not be the answer.

Comment: what have you thought about this?

Comment: Let x be the number of cards to be thrown away.  The prob. of getting the remaining cards is (1-(x/48)).
Then multiplied by the prob of getting 4 aces is 4/(52-x).

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{x}{4}=\dfrac{x!}{(x-4)!\times 4!}=1001$$

$$\implies \dfrac{x\times (x-1) \times (x-2) \times (x-3)}{4!}=1001$$

$$\implies \dfrac{x^4-6x^3+11x^2-6x}{24}=1001$$
$$ \implies x = 14 \text{ or } x = -11$$

So I'll say that 14 cards are remaining.

Comment: Don't you have negative cards at home?

Comment: Why is the required prob. equal to 1/(xC4) ?

Answer (score 0):

Call $ x $ the number of cards thrown away and $ y = 52-x $ the number of remaining cards.

The number of ways of selecting 4 cards out of $ y $ is $ \binom{y}{4} $ but only 1 of those cases is the one you are interested in (all four aces) so the probability is $ \frac{1}{\binom{y}{4}} $. Also, you are told that the probablity is $ \frac{1}{1001} $. Hence, $ \frac{1}{\binom{y}{4}} = \frac{1}{1001} \implies \binom{y}{4} = 1001 $. Find $ y $, and then $ x = 52 - y $